# Sending data with Publish channel in maximo

Tags: json, xml, maximo

When you "export" data with the external system and publist channel in maximo, is it possible that the response you send will be in JSON? Because I can only get it in XML.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for : https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/IBM%20Maximo%20Asset%20Management/page/Maximo%20JSON%20API ?

Comment: No, these are not the documennts that i am looking for...

Answer (score 0):

how about using an XSLT that coverts xml to json.